# How to consolidate/clean up .querySelector elements

Tags: javascript, html, function, jquery-selectors

I have multiple of the same function `toggleImage`. I have them all written out in separate lines of code and they all function fine but I'm sure there's a more efficient way to write this.

I have tried `document.querySelectorAll('#H01Overlay', '#H02Overlay', '#H03Overlay', '#H04Overlay')` but then my functions all stop working...

```js
function toggleImage(){
  document.querySelector('#H01Overlay').classList.toggle('img-hidden');
}

function toggleImage(){
  document.querySelector('#H02Overlay').classList.toggle('img-hidden');
}

function toggleImage(){
  document.querySelector('#H03Overlay').classList.toggle('img-hidden');
}

function toggleImage(){
  document.querySelector('#H04Overlay').classList.toggle('img-hidden');
}
```

Comment: `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()` expect **one** string containing one or more css selectors. `'#H01Overlay', '#H02Overlay', '#H03Overlay', '#H04Overlay'` are four separate strings (selectors). Make it one and it will work.

Comment: Can you share enough of your "*[mcve]*" HTML to allow us to reproduce your problem? There are many ways to select elements and achieve what you seem to want other than using an element's `id`, including taking advantage of the DOM structure to make your JavaScript more DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** Function names have to be unique. But you could have combined them to one function:

```js
function toggleImage(){
  document.querySelector('#H01Overlay').classList.toggle('img-hidden');
  document.querySelector('#H02Overlay').classList.toggle('img-hidden');
  document.querySelector('#H03Overlay').classList.toggle('img-hidden');
  document.querySelector('#H04Overlay').classList.toggle('img-hidden');
}
```

---

Like mentioned before, you can use multiple selectors in a comma-separated string (with `querySelectorAll`). You need a loop to toggle the class of each element from this selection.

**Working example:**

```js
function toggleImage(){
  let elms = document.querySelectorAll('#H01Overlay, #H02Overlay, #H03Overlay, #H04Overlay');
  
  for(i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    elms[i].classList.toggle('img-hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
.img-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="H01Overlay">test</div>
<div id="H02Overlay">test</div>
<div id="H03Overlay">test</div>
<div id="H04Overlay">test</div>
<div id="H05Overlay">test</div>

<button type="button" onclick="toggleImage();">toggle</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, biberman! This example is a massive help.

Answer (score 2):

querySelectorAll requires one arguement, but the selector can be multiple. Did you try this?

```
document.querySelectorAll('#H01Overlay,#H02Overlay,#H03Overlay,#H04Overlay');
```